# My 2002 Ford Explorer XLT revs up when at a complete stop

Tags: ford, explorer

It runs fine and the problem only happens once in a while, when i stop at a redlight it revs up and feels like it wants to accelerate on it's own

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please tell us what engine, if it is an automatic or standard transmission, are there any obstructions around the brake and accelerator pedal, and if you have checked the throttle cables for damage or obstructions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very general question but usually this is one thing in particular.

Your idle air control valve needs to be replaced. this regulates the air control while at idle, and so it would only engage when the vehicle is at a rest.

It could also be a vacuum leak, or a failed sensor, however the most likely culprit is the IACV. If you have anyone that knows what they are doing have them check for ODB codes (not every code trips the check engine light), conduct a vacuum test, and test the IACV.

An easy way to test the IACV is, in a controlled environment, get the engine up to temperature and when the revving occurs unplug the IACV and it should stabilize to "base idle" revs (500 rpm or so). If it stabilizes than it's a faulty IACV.

This is the #1 most common issue in 02 Ford Explorers with the 92% chance to fix being the IACV.